# Where can I find a list of values for EXTRA_ONLINE?

Tags: android, batterymanager

I'm trying to build a profile for the Tasker app that responds to the BATTERY_CHANGED broadcast intent and I saw one of the Extras called Online that appears to correspond with the specific charger type or condition, but I can't seem to find a proper list of potential values for this Extra.  At best, I've found a few of the values, such as 1 being None, 4 is USB, 10 is Wireless, 100 is Fast Wireless. Others I have just guessed at, such as 6 being a QuickCharge 2.0 or 3.0 type charger and 19 being a Power Delivery charger, but otherwise I can't be sure.
Is there any official documentation for this Extra in Android P?

Answer (score 0):

There's surprisingly little documentation about the `online` extra!

I found this list which seems to be from [a decompiled Samsung Pay app](https://github.com/pandalion98/SPay-inner-workings/blob/master/boot.oat_files/arm64/dex/out0/android/os/BatteryManager.java), weirdly enough:

```
public static final int BATTERY_ONLINE_FAST_WIRELESS_CHARGER = 100;
public static final int BATTERY_ONLINE_INCOMPATIBLE_CHARGER = 0;
public static final int BATTERY_ONLINE_NONE = 1;
public static final int BATTERY_ONLINE_POGO = 23;
public static final int BATTERY_ONLINE_TA = 3;
public static final int BATTERY_ONLINE_USB = 4;
public static final int BATTERY_ONLINE_WATER_IN_CONNECTOR = 101;
public static final int BATTERY_ONLINE_WIRELESS_CHARGER = 10;
```

The values seem to match with almost all of yours, I do find it very odd that seems to be no other record of them (from a quick Google).

Despite the `android.os` package of the linked file, perhaps it's not part of the OS / has been changed / has a different name. Maybe a Samsung-specific feature?

Comment: I suspect you're right that this is a Samsung specific Extra, as I found these values on my Galaxy Note9.  More than that, the POGO and TA values in your list correspond to chargers used with Samsung devices. The POGO chargers also work on some Nexus tablets, although the Nexus 10 was also made by Samsung, so that still supports the theory that this Extra might be specific to Samsung.

Comment: @Ceetch Ah, your extra info definitely suggests that then. Unfortunately it looks like that might be the end of the road, since almost all Samsung stuff is closed source. Also explains why it's only on a decompiled Samsung app, seemingly nowhere else. Mystery solved!?